# Use Created datetime in keywordquery

Tags: search, keywordquery

I want to use the Created column in my keywoard query, like this:

```
  KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
  query.QueryText = "ContentType=\"Vraag\""; // AND TaskStatus<>Voltooid";
  query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
  query.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
  query.SelectProperties.Add("Path");
  query.SelectProperties.Add("OrderNumber");
  query.SelectProperties.Add("Created");

  ResultTableCollection resultsCollection = query.Execute();
  ResultTable results = resultsCollection[ResultType.RelevantResults];

  DataTable result = new DataTable();
  result.Load(results, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

But I can't find how to use the Created datetime field. I know there is a Write property that can be used, but that is the modified datetime.

Does anyone know how to use the Created datetime field in a KeyWordQuery?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

As Amit suggested, create a new managed property (CreatedDate) of type Date and Time.

Map it to these Crawled Properties

1. Basic:15(Date and Time)
2. ows_Start_x0020_Date(Date and Time)
3. ows_StartDate(Date and Time)
4. Office:12(Date and Time)
5. creationdate(Date and Time)

And select `Include values from a single crawled property based on the order specified`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the Search administration, You can create a new managed property (*CreatedDate* for example) and map it to `ows_Created` crawled property.

After a crawl, you should be able to use it like you need:

```
query.SelectProperties.Add("CreatedDate");
```

Comment: I have actually tried this and I get null back in Created Date.  Also, in the SharePoint search results page - created date is included?

Comment: Did you do a crawl after creating and mapping new managed property?

Comment: Yep - certainly did!

Comment: The search clearly has the created date though - to be able to show it in the search results page - so how can we get a handle on it I wonder!!!!?